# How to get params from android.intent.action.SEND

Tags: android

I have registered my activity in the manifest as android.intent.action.SEND.
Now, after pressing SHARE on every app, my application pops - which is great, but I didn't understand how do I fetch the parameters the other app sent to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters you want to extract are called extras. You can extract them this way:

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] recipients = (String[]) extras.get(EXTRA_EMAIL);
```

There are several extras you can get from an ACTION_SEND intent (e.g. EXTRA_EMAIL, EXTRA_CC, EXTRA_BCC, EXTRA_SUBJECT). Take a look at the [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) to get an overview

Answer (score 0):

Google provides all the info about it very well explained:

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html
how to set the manifest, receive the data and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String name = intent.EXTRA_EMAIL.concat(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```