# How to get image detail from android.intent.action.SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, metadata, intentfilter

I want something like this.

[image]

NOT the UI, **just the data**. (The metadata of an image)
In Chrome or some other browser when I browse I get a grid or a list of pictures and when I long press on any image it shows "Share image" option. So when I click on "Share image."

> I want my application (**REQUIREMENTS**)
>
> 1. to show up in the chooser dialog. (**Working**)
> 2. Retrieve info about the image (title, URL, thumbnail) (**Not working**)

I have done the opposite many times (Sharing some link from my application to another Application like Gmail, WhatsApp, etc).
 My question is if it is even possible at all?  I have seen many application doing that( You can see in the image ) and have no idea how do they do that.

> Here is what I have done so far in terms of code.

### Requirement 1 (Working)

I have an activity registered with `android.intent.action.SEND` intent filter in manifest. (Which makes my activity to appear in the list of Chooser dialog)

Here is the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

### Requirement 2 (NOT Working)

Here is the Activity code to retrieve the data.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phot_save_layout);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);

        takeValueFunc();
    }

    public void takeValueFunc()
    {
        Intent shareIntent = getIntent();
        if(shareIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
        {
            String text = shareIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        }
    }

}
```

I have done some digging with different browsers, and I read different values for the same image.
I have found a similar question on StackOverflow [How to get params from android.intent.action.SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233415/how-to-get-params-from-android-intent-action-send)

But it does not answer my question. :(

Comment: You can extract all from getIntent(). There is all what you put in at starting the action. Nothing less. Nothing more. So investigate the intent.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. How to figure out which key value will give me what. for eg shareIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
 gives me url if it is plain text. but it does not work if it is an image. (null value). Any relevant link ? @greenapps

Comment: Then start with showing the intent that shares it. And shiwwhat you trued besides EXTRA_TEXT.

Comment: I want to send data from browser to my app. Like we browse some image in google and we see a grid of images. When we long press on any image it shows options like (Copy link text, copy link , share image etc). So when i click on the share image option it opens in my app . Got the idea ? @jiteshmohite

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want my application to... Retrieve info about the image (title, url, thumbnail)

That is not possible in general.

You are welcome to peruse through [the documented extras for `ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). You are welcome to come up with your own algorithm for deciding how to interpret those extras. However, there is no requirement that you get the information that you are seeking.

For example, `EXTRA_STREAM` may hold a `Uri`. That `Uri` should have a `content` scheme. That `Uri`, plus a `ContentResolver`, should give you the concrete MIME type (as the MIME type on the `Intent` may be a wildcard). If that is an image, you can use your favorite image-loading library to load the image into your thumbnail-sized visual representation.

But that's it.

*Maybe* `EXTRA_TEXT` and/or `EXTRA_SUBJECT` will hold other information you might use, but there is no requirement that, say, the HTTPS URL of the image be in either of those. After all, there may not *be* an HTTPS URL of the image, as the image may not be on the Internet. Similarly, the sending app may not *have* a "title", let alone send it as part of `ACTION_SEND` somehow.

Comment: Actually it makes sense because Chrome and Firefox are too android application. And they may or may not share those information in android.Intent.SEND. But i wonder how other application retrieve those data with the same link and same intent ? Is there any concept which relates to it? Any hint or link would be appreciated . And thanks for your reply.   @Commonsware

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content) link to see how to receive data from other apps. However the example you have provided doesn't fit the scenario. WhatsApp is receiving only the link and generating preview by itself. If you want to do the same, you can use [social metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews) or similar service.

Comment: I ahve already gone through the first link. But it does not specify what key value i should use to retrieve the values. Like the image title ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which data browser shares but you may analyze it, because it's all that you have.

To read all extras from intent:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        Log.d("Entry", String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", key, extras.get(key)));
    }
```

Also there are open graph protocol to obtain web page preview so if browser shared the url then you may obtain meta info about this page(title, preview etc)

Info at provided screenshot obtained with opengraph.

http://ogp.me/ open graph site

Open graph debugger by facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

NB: some social networks defined their protocols to describe page preview (eg [Twitter cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started))

Also I found this opengraph client for java: https://github.com/johndeverall/opengraph-java

Answer (score 0):

** I think this code for working to share the  detail in whatApp with Image.**

```
            PackageManager pm = fragmentContext.getPackageManager();
            try {
                Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                if (Common.nonNull(bitmapUri))
                    waIntent.setType("image/*");
                String text = invite.getInviteMessage();
                PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                waIntent.setPackage(info.packageName);
                waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(fragmentContext, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the opposite of my question. I want to get those data from other application to my application. I have one question for you. How did you figure out this piece of information--->PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is [Rich Link Preview Support.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews) You can [create your own dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create) with rich preview support.

On the other hand, to [receiving simple datas from other app](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#update-manifest) to your own app can be done by adding intent filters to activity which represents that able to handle process in [AndroidManifest.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)